# Python split a column into multiple columns based on ranges

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column in my dataframe and it has values between 2100 and 8000. I want to split this column into multiple columns of intervals of 500. So let me show you by example:

```
   column
    2100
    2105
    2119
     .
    8000
```

I want to split it like this:

```
   column1   column2 column3  .   .  column n
    2100        0       0     .   .    0
      .         0       .     .   .    0
    2600        0       0
              2601      0     .   .    .
                .       .
              3101      0
                       3102            0
                        .
                       3602                  
                                      8000
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: is the column sorted?

Comment: what about the holes? lets say you have all the numbers between 1 and 500 but only 3 numbers between 501 and 1000, should all the numbers be on top? what do you want in the holes? the data frame has to be rectangular, you can have columns of varying lengths

Comment: That is the case, there are holes. @yatu

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(2100, 8000+1)), columns=['column'])
# create the bins to be used in pd.cut
bins = list(range(df.column.min(), df.column.max()+50, 50))
# array([2100, 2150, 2200, 2250, 2300 ...
# Create the labels for pd.cut, which will be used as column names
labels = [f'column{i}' for i in range(len(bins)-1)]
# ['column0', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', ...
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.column, bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
```

Which will give you:

```
      column       bins
0       2100    column0
1       2101    column0
2       2102    column0
3       2103    column0
4       2104    column0
5       2105    column0
6       2106    column0
7       2107    column0
8       2108    column0
```

And now use `pivot` to obtain the final result:

```
ix = df.groupby('bins').column.cumcount()
df.pivot(columns = 'bins', index=ix).fillna(0)

bins column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8  ... 
0     2100.0  2151.0  2201.0  2251.0  2301.0  2351.0  2401.0  2451.0  2501.0   
1     2101.0  2152.0  2202.0  2252.0  2302.0  2352.0  2402.0  2452.0  2502.0   
2     2102.0  2153.0  2203.0  2253.0  2303.0  2353.0  2403.0  2453.0  2503.0   
3     2103.0  2154.0  2204.0  2254.0  2304.0  2354.0  2404.0  2454.0  2504.0   
4     2104.0  2155.0  2205.0  2255.0  2305.0  2355.0  2405.0  2455.0  2505.0   
5     2105.0  2156.0  2206.0  2256.0  2306.0  2356.0  2406.0  2456.0  2506.0   
6     2106.0  2157.0  2207.0  2257.0  2307.0  2357.0  2407.0  2457.0  2507.0   
7     2107.0  2158.0  2208.0  2258.0  2308.0  2358.0  2408.0  2458.0  2508.0   
8     2108.0  2159.0  2209.0  2259.0  2309.0  2359.0  2409.0  2459.0  2509.0   
9     2109.0  2160.0  2210.0  2260.0  2310.0  2360.0  2410.0  2460.0  2510.0   
10    2110.0  2161.0  2211.0  2261.0  2311.0  2361.0  2411.0  2461.0  2511.0  
...
```

---

Lets encapsulate it all in a function, and try with a simpler example to better see how this works:

```
def binning_and_pivot(df, bin_size):
    bins = list(range(df.column.min(), df.column.max()+bin_size, bin_size))
    labels = [f'column{i}' for i in range(len(bins)-1)]
    df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.column, bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
    ix = df.groupby('bins').column.cumcount()
    return df.pivot(columns = 'bins', index=ix).fillna(0)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(100+1)), columns=['column'])
df = df.sample(frac=0.7).reset_index(drop=True)
binning_and_pivot(df, bin_size=10)

bins column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8   
0        2.0    16.0    32.0    39.0    45.0    55.0    69.0    81.0    87.0   
1        6.0    21.0    29.0    42.0    46.0    59.0    72.0    76.0    92.0   
2        3.0    13.0    31.0    36.0    49.0    61.0    68.0    74.0    91.0   
3       12.0    20.0    25.0    41.0    52.0    56.0    70.0    78.0    86.0   
4        8.0    17.0    30.0    37.0    43.0    62.0    64.0    73.0    89.0   
5        7.0    19.0    27.0    38.0    50.0    53.0    71.0    77.0    83.0   
6        0.0    22.0    28.0     0.0     0.0    54.0    65.0    82.0    90.0   
7        0.0    18.0    24.0     0.0     0.0    60.0    63.0    80.0     0.0   
8        0.0    14.0    26.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    75.0     0.0   


bins column9  
0       95.0  
1      100.0  
2       96.0  
3        0.0  
4        0.0  
5        0.0  
6        0.0  
7        0.0  
8        0.0
```

Comment: The data in the input column is a random range. Please see the edit

Comment: Just checked it and i think it should still work fine @Nofy

Comment: I think this method will work. As it stands you will get NaNs for the empty rows, change the last line of the solution to get zeros as shown in the edited question: `df.pivot(columns = 'bins', index=ix).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my choice of action

I did it for intervals of 4

NOTE the number of rows must by fully divided by the intervals

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'Z:\Path\neww.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

didi = df.to_dict()
num = 4
dd={}
for i in range(int(len(didi['column'].items())/num)):
    dd['col' + str(i)] = dict(list(didi['column'].items())[i*num:num*(i+1)])
print(pd.DataFrame(dd).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)))
```

Input:

```
column
2100
2100
2100
2100
2100
2100
2100
2100
2100
2100
8000
8000
8000
8000
8000
8000
8000
8000
80
8000
```

Output:

```
     col0    col1    col2    col3    col4
0  2100.0  2100.0  2100.0  8000.0  8000.0
1  2100.0  2100.0  2100.0  8000.0  8000.0
2  2100.0  2100.0  8000.0  8000.0    80.0
3  2100.0  2100.0  8000.0  8000.0  8000.0
```

Answer (score -1):

see the documentation of `numpy.reshape`.

Suppose you extract your concerned data into a numpy array, say `data`. Here's a possible solution.

```
newdata = data.reshape((500, -1))
```

`newdata` is your reshaped data